# Replace SqlDataSource with EntityDataSource

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework

I have a DataGrid *(destination)* with a *countryID* column, this is binded to a DropDownList to view the countries. I have *countries* and *countryGroups* tables too, where *countries.countryGroupId = countryGroups.countryGroupId*. The list have to be formatted therefore I use SqlDataSource to get the formatted list:

```
SELECT   c.countryID, cg.countryGroupName+': '+c.CountryName as Name
FROM     countries AS c INNER JOIN
         countries_groups AS cg ON c.countryGroupID = cg.countryGroupID
ORDER BY cg.Sort, c.CountryName
```

here's the dropdownlist originally binded to sqldatasource:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlCountryID" runat="server" Width="160px" DataSourceID="dsCountries"
     AppendDataBoundItems="true"  DataTextField="Name" DataValueField="countryID" 
     SelectedValue='<%# Bind("countryID") %>'>
     <asp:ListItem Value="" Text="Select"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

I would like to replace the SqlDataSource to EntityDataSource for the country field. I created the following *ProductionModel*

[image: ProductionModel.edmx]

VS2010 has been created the public partial class **ProductionEntities : ObjectContext**...
I created an EntityDataSource:

```
<asp:EntityDataSource ID="EntityDataSource1" runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="name=ProductionEntities" 
    DefaultContainerName="ProductionEntities" EntitySetName="countries" 
    Include="" 
    onquerycreated="EntityDataSource1_QueryCreated" 
    ContextTypeName="ASPWebApp.Datasource.ProductionEntities">
```

My question is, **what other steps are needed to finalyze the binding with EntityDataSource?**
Thanks in advance!

**UPDATE:**
The solution became to be as follows (thanks to @Gaurav Jain)

```
protected void ddlCountryID_OnInit(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  DropDownList ddlCountryID = sender as DropDownList;
  ddlCountryID.DataSource = (from c in db.suppliers_countries
                             join cg in db.suppliers_countries_groups on c.countryGroupID equals cg.countryGroupID
                             orderby cg.Sort, c.CountryName
                             select new {
                                    c.countryID,
                                    Name = cg.countryGroupName + ": " + c.CountryName
                             });
}
```

and dropdownlist became to be:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlCountryID" runat="server" Width="160px" AppendDataBoundItems="true"  
                  SelectedValue='<%# Bind("countryID") %>' **OnInit="ddlCountryID_OnInit"**  
                  DataTextField="Name" DataValueField="countryID">
                  <asp:ListItem Value="" Text="Select"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

Comment: It seemed like all is done (only I can't see connection string in web.config). For improve performance may I advise to use Stored Procedure instead of Sql query.

Comment: Is it compulsory to use web forms? Why don't u use html select with Knockjout.Js + WebApi for example?

Comment: No, it is not all done at all. It misses the JOIN from entitydatasource, between countries and countries_groups. That is the main incompleteness. Yes, it is compulsory to use webforms. I would like to hold business logic on server side instead of javascript.

Comment: Well, you must clarify your question. It should be "How should I improve my data access layer and sql query paticullary". Java Scriprt labreries like Knockout they are responsible for data presentation, business logic are always on server side, but novadays there is much better solutions - WebApi or MVC. Regarding your question - use Stored Procedure in your Entity Data Source.

Comment: just check answer below.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use this query.

```
       ProductionEntities db = new ProductionEntities();
       ddlCountryID.DataSource = (from c in db.countries 
                                  join cg in db.countries_groups on c.countryGroupID       
                                  equals cg.countryGroupID 
                                  select new 
                                  { c.countryID,   
                                    Name = cg.countryGroupName + " " + c.CountryName,cg.Sort})
                                   .OrderBy(w => new {w.countryID,w.sort });      
        ddlCountryID.DataTextField = "Name";
        ddlCountryID.DataValueField = "countryID";
        ddlCountryID.DataBind();
```

Comment: I had just change the code this will solve your issue check it now.

Comment: Where should I place this code snipet? Form_Load for instance?

Comment: bind your grid view at time of page_load. and after that put this code inside this.

Comment: inside GridView1_RowDataBound event